# Spring REST Multimodule with Maven/Gradle

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, multi-module

I'm making bigger project in Spring with maven.

Currently there is one core-app and several additional services. Basically core-app can work without any of the additional apps and the additional apps can work on different hosts and port. To manage this i've created additional app in python which is able to clone, pull, start and stop those modules, or change configuration which is held in xml file. But I've heard that this is not a good idea to create whole new app just to manage those projects (like big init file on steroids) and I should do this with multimodules.

The problem is I want to be able to run this in many configuration and to add/remove module without big changes in configuration file and be able to run modules in any combination. I want to run only module 1 or only 1 and 3 and so on, i don't want to create maven build for every combination (image to add 2 modules to 5 and make all combination from scratch). I'm trying to do this with gradle too but i don't see way to run 2 spring boot apps in row with one command (because when the first one starts to run the building is stopped because spring don't want to end, because it should be running all the time an i just want to log it to file in background).

I hope I've described that problem quite good and please suggest me anything I can do or tell me whether creating additional app to do that is good or not.